# NO_POLL websocket server on esp8266 rtos sdk

Tags: sdk, esp8266, freertos

I'm trying to use the nopoll library provided with the RTOS sdk for the esp8266, to build a websockets server.

I've followed the example provided on the no_poll website namely:

```
noPollConn * listener = nopoll_listener_new (ctx, "0.0.0.0", "1234");
if (! nopoll_conn_is_ok (listener)) {
     // some error handling here
}

nopoll_ctx_set_on_msg (ctx, listener_on_message, NULL);

nopoll_loop_wait (ctx, 0);
```

with an appropriate callback:

```
void listener_on_message (noPollCtx * ctx, noPollConn * conn, noPollMsg * msg, noPollPtr  user_data) {

        printf ("Listener received (size: %d, ctx refs: %d): (first %d bytes, fragment: %d) '%s'\n", 
                nopoll_msg_get_payload_size (msg),
                nopoll_ctx_ref_count (ctx), shown, nopoll_msg_is_fragment (msg), example);


        nopoll_conn_send_text (conn, "Message received", 16);

        return;
}
```

But the process does nothing!

Has anyone else been able to make this work?

Or is it just broken?

In the examples directory for the RTOS, a websockets send example is provided, which is a cut down version of the test suite for the standard NO_POLL library. I noticed that the tests which are removed include the
tests for server creation.

Any help which you can provide would be welcomed!

BR